# Where are systemd controlled Celery Task failures and Python excpetions logged?

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging, celery, systemd

I have python tasks that are scheduled and executed by Celery using systemd on an Ubuntu production server. There are 3 log files that I am aware of:

1 This entry in the worker service creates a log file that lists incoming received tasks

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
-A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
--logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
```

2 This entry in the beat service creates a log file that lists dispatched beat tasks

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} beat  \
-A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE} \
-s ${CELERYBEAT_DB_FILE} \
--logfile=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'
```

3 I have custom logging that uses standard python `import logging`

Now these 3 files work as expected. However if the python code in my tasks raises an exception, I cannot see it logged anywhere. If I manually insert an error, for example an illegal import that will raise an exception, then I can see this in log (3) when I manually run the task on the command line. If however the systemd service initiates this exception, it cannot be seen in log (3). Even if I make the forced error task run every minute for example, I can see it being dispatched correctly in log (2), received in log (1), then my code logging to log (3) until it hits the exception whereupon the logging in log (3) doesn't record this.

Does anybody know where this python exception will be logged? And also, if there is any log on my system that shows that the task failed and why?

Many thanks, LJHW

Comment: which log handler are you using? Wit the logging package you can define where and how logs should be stored the default is stdout I think. You can also use the `from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger` package

Comment: I am using a custom queued multi-process timed-rotating logger set in `@after_setup_logger.connect` in my tasks and by `logging.config.fileConfig` in my code.

Comment: In the `@after_setup_logger.connect` can you try to add the following `fh = logging.FileHandler('logs.log')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)` To test if the logs end up in the file

Comment: My logging works fine. In fact I have now added a complete `try except' around the entire task, so I can see what causes the task to fail. My point still stands though : where does the systemd/rabbitmq/celery system log that a task failed? and where does it log the exception that was thrown causing it to fail?